# DNN CMS login Issue

Tags: dotnetnuke, citrix

I have 3 DNN webservers behind a Citrix Load Balancer, the load balancer is configured for SSL Offloading.

I discovered that the login link doesn't work anymore. It just refreshes whenever it is clicked. The URL of the login is: [Login](https://test.abc.net/User-Login?returnurl=%2F). The link when clicked supposed to take users to the page where they will login.

When I changed d citrix load balancer to HTTP, everything thing works normal. I.e [Login](http://test.abc.net/User-Login?returnurl=%2F). Opened the Login Page.

Any suggestion on how to resolve this issue will be appreciated.

Comment: What happens when you try to specify a return-page? eg:
/Login?returnurl=%2fYour-Page-Here


Do you have the DNN installed as SSL enabled, and the pages (login page) set as "secure"?

Comment: No, SSL was not enabled at d server side and Login pages are not set as "secure". The DNN installation was based on d default settings. Everything works fine if I change Citrix Load Balancer vserver to "HTTP"; things woks fine if I connect directly to the Web Servers over "HTTP". Issue is with SSL Offloading.